# I can connect to windows 7 host, but not vise versa

Tags: windows-7, lan, connection, gaming

I didn't know where else to look because this problem is so unique, and random, that it has me at a total loss. Maybe someone here has an idea.

Description:

2 players, both on zerotier, playing Rainbow 6 Vegas via LAN coop.

Player 1 has windows 10 pro v1909.18363.449
Player 2 has windows 7 ultimate sp1

When win10 hosts a lan game, win7 is able to see it in the in-game browser, however, after trying to connect to it, they receive an "unable to connect to server" error. Win10 user has tried opening all his ports, does not use windows firewall, and yet still has the same result when win7 tries to connect. If win7 tries to connect with any other game (usually post 2010) they have no problems at all.

When win7 hosts, win10 can see their server fine--just like win7 could, ping, players and all--and is able to connect and load into their lobby without trouble, and then play.

Why not just play this way? win7's connection is poor, and it's lag city in there, making it impossible to play--rubber banding, stutters, etc, etc.

Now, the question is: how come win10 can not be connected to when everything has been tried in regards to opening ports and is able to be seen by win7? Is there a protocol problem with Vegas? Is there some sort of client side change in the OS that would allow this older type of connect to be enabled to win7 but no win10? A registry or component issue?

I am lost, and any help would be greatly appreciated. It's just puzzling to know that he can see my server fine, and I can connect to his and play, but he cannot connect to mine and play.

(note: I have tried DMZ through my router, windows firewall is not installed on my OS, changing and configuring dns/ip addresses and option configurations in zerotier. A different tunneler/VPN. It should also be noted, that later versions/builds of windows10 that I've tried won't even load this game after the UE logo screen but mine does.)

---

**for anyone having the same problem for this particular game, a solution is to use Game Ranger, as it hooks the exe and piggy backs your protocol, however, the problem in general as to why the game refuses to connect via win7 to win10 or even win10 to win10 (depending on the build) is unanswered.

Comment: Define "see". Are you entering the server's zerotier IP address into the game, or is the game supposed to find it automatically via broadcast? How many nodes are in the zerotier network, total?

Comment: There is a browser that will automatically show the server when it is created by the game, in the game, and you see that person's/player's hosted game. There is only us two on the zerotier network on the same ip block.

Comment: If you run Wireshark on both machines, capturing on the ZeroTier interface, do they both show the "discovery" packets that the game uses? (Either the server sends a broadcast packet to 255.255.255.255 and clients pick it up, or the _client_ sends the broadcast and servers respond.) In the past, broadcast & multicast was something ZeroTier kinda struggled with.

Comment: If that were the case, why would I be able to connect to him fine but not vise versa?